# How can parent class method return child class type? Doesn't this violate inheritance?

Tags: java, string, oop, object

Since `Object` class is considered the base class of all the classes in Java, how can it have return type of `String` in `.toString()` method, since `String` class is a child class of `Object` class?

Doesn't this violate inheritance because the parent class knows about the child class?

Comment: In what way? What exactly do you think that's violating?

Comment: Inheritance... How does the parent class knows about the child class ?

Comment: Thanks @Duncan, I'll follow this in future.

Answer (score 1):

Very simply, inheritance does not require that a parent class knows nothing about its child classes.

So it's totally fine for a parent class to make reference to child classes. It would be rather challenging to produce any hierarchical type system without this!

Comment: isn't it becomes cyclic ?

Comment: @Pavan No. The relationship between a parent class and a child class is fixed. Just because a parent class returns a child class instance, doesn't suddenly reverse the relationship in any way.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Object().toString();
```

and

```
String s =(String) new Object();
```

are definitely two different things. Your objection makes sense if related to the second instruction: that's the one dealing with inheritance, not the first.
Infact, that's a narrowing operation, that will result in a RuntimeException.

Answer (score 0):

Well, type of is a operation that check class types... Nothing to do with inheritance.... when you output an object with .toString() you basically get a String returned. That is why you your type of return true... toString() is a method that all Classes inherit, regardless of useful or not.

Comment: Yes, but the question was that in order to "define" a `Object` at compile time you need to have a `String` type. And in order to define the `String` type you need its parent the `Object`. So to me the question looks usefull. (I dont have a detailed answer but Java deals with partially resolved types (if it knows it has to produce a method with return type String this is enough to compile object, it doesnt need the String at that moment). Those cyclic dependencies are not restricted to `Object` or jcl classes.

Comment: @eckes Thanks for understanding my question clearly. Now I've another question is it a good practice to return the child class type in parent class method in our own implementations ?

Comment: The typical pattern is differently, the base class has a more generic return type than the child class. But I guess there might be cases where it makes sense the other way around (I just cant think of any :) Keep in mind, if you return "yourself" a caller can still treat you as your parent (and can not access shadowed methods no matter what type you return).

Comment: @eckes it makes sense when you write a network interface serializing simple Object extensions as e.g.:

You have a mobile app and a server. The mobile app get all kinds of information from the server. In this case you could call every information sent across a Message(Message extends Object). Then you serialize the message and forward it to the server. The server then retrieves the object and check what type of message.

This is the only way I can recall how I created a sloppy Socket based networkinterface not using rmi in the past.

Comment: @eckes exactly!!! that's where polymorphism come into play. And even I find more difficult to bring the same scenario like Object-String relation. But as of now I come to a conclusion that String becomes very necessary in java which made them to implement in this way. When I accepts this way another question raising in my mind "Then why String aren't created as primitive type in Java ? "

Comment: Just to make that clear, there is no special handling for Object/String dependencies. Java generally deals with those cycles. It does not need to resolve the types when declaring classes or interfaces.